# Another appendchild not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a appendChild JS function that works beautifully in all the browsers except IE.

I am using a JS array and appending this data to a table.

http://jsfiddle.net/2waZ2/51/   Has the code - and works fine in fiddle!

I have looked around the other answers and their problems seem to be a bit different to mine.  Maybe I just need to make a tbody, but I dont really know how to do that.

Whats the best way to rewrite this to work in Ie?

Append code part as in the fiddle:

```
var row =  document.createElement('tr');
row.innerHTML = displayArrayAsTable(QR4, 24, 25);
document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild( row ) ; 

function displayArrayAsTable( array, from, to ) {
  var array = array || [],
  from = from || 0,
  to = to || 0;
 var html = '';

 if ( array.length < 1 )
{
  return;
}
if ( to == 0 )
{
    to = array.length - 1;
}
for ( var x = from; x < to + 1; x++ )
 {
html += '<td>' + array[x] + '</td>';
}
 return html;
}
```

Comment: You want this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.insertRow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to use [`insertRow` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.insertRow):

```
var row = document.getElementById('mytable').insertRow(-1);
row.innerHTML = displayArrayAsTable(QR4, 24, 25);
```

As for `tBody`: Yes, that could be the problem. The browser *always* generates a `tBody` element, no matter whether it is specified in the HTML or not.
Maybe you can solve your problem by just appending the new row to this `tBody` element:

```
document.getElementById('mytable').tBodies[0].appendChild( row );
```

But I remember reading that IE had problems with manipulating tables with normal DOM manipulation methods. Whether this applies in this case as well, I don't know. `insertRow` should work in any case.

**Update:** Indeed, it seems that IE does not like to append `td` elements with `innerHTML` either. A solution would be to pass `row` also as parameter to `displayArrayAsTable` and use [`insertCell` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/tableRow.insertCell) to create a new cell.

**Update 2:** For example you can do it like this:

```
for ( var x = from; x < to + 1; x++ )
{
    var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
    cell.innerHTML = array[x];
}
```

where `row` is a fourth parameter of the function and called as:

```
var row = document.getElementById('mytable').insertRow(-1);
displayArrayAsTable(QR4, 24, 25, row);
```

Comment: I tried it and I dont see it working - http://bakerscottage.com/xx.html  fine in Firefox, not in IE?

Comment: I added the displayArrayAsTable code.  I got it from here.  I was trying the insetCell from the MDN, as I saw it worked on IE. But I couldnt get more than one cell or integrate it with my array.  Im a bit of a novice at this. Any chance I could see an example of how to do this with my code?

Comment: Took me a while to work out how to apply the code even though it was handed on a plate.  Works a dream.  Thanks so much.  I think im slowly getting it...

Comment: Seems I have many row vars.  row1 row2 row3 row4 etc  Now that it is in the displayArrayAsTable function the only way I can make multiple row vars is to make multiple functions displayArrayAsTable1 holding row1 displayArrayAsTable2 holding row2 etc.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @Jon: You should pass the row as parameter to the function.

Comment: I cant use the adding cell in the function.  I have something else that adds and removes the tr line.  With the cell in the function, when I add it back in - It puts double the info in.  I dont know why, but i think its linked to this.  There must be a way to take the row var out of the function?