# Are rows and cells dynamic collections?

Tags: javascript, html, rows, cells

In JavaScript, are rows and cells dynamic collections?

For example:

```
var myRows=myTable.rows;
var newRow=myTable.insertRow();
```

Will newRow automatically become part of myRows?

Sorry if it seems like a basic question, but I couldn't find any reference with a clear answer.

Comment: @mrtsherman If you just try it and see, it may be implementation dependent. Best to find an official source first, and then test if your interpretation of it is correct.

Comment: @Christophe this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678178/another-appendchild-not-working-in-ie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table.rows` is* an `HTMLCollection` which is [live](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506).

> An `HTMLCollection` is a list of nodes. An individual node may be accessed by either ordinal index or the node's `name` or `id` attributes.
>
> Note: Collections in the HTML DOM are assumed to be **live** meaning that they are automatically updated when the underlying document is changed.

---

* As specified [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/ecma-script-language-binding.html):

> Object `HTMLTableElement`
>
> ...
>
> `rows`
>
> This property is of type `HTMLCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try it and see:

http://jsfiddle.net/xfecU/

```
<table>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
    var myTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
    var myRows=myTable.rows;
    alert(myRows.length); //alerts 1
    var newRow=myTable.insertRow();
    alert(myRows.length); //alerts 2
</script>​
```

So yes.

Comment: Same comment as @MrLister: an example doesn't cover all browsers and edge cases. I am looking for an official reference.